# Python SQLITE3 SELECT query with datetime calculated string not working

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a SQLite3 DB with a table named `TEST_TABLE`, which looks like this:

```
("ID" TEXT,"DATE_IN" DATE,"WEEK_IN" number);
```

There are 2 entries in the table:

```
1|2012-03-25|13
2|2013-03-25|13
```

I'm trying to write a query that returns the ID for week 13 of this year.
I want to use the program again next year, so I cannot hardcode "2013" as the year.

I used datetime to calculate a value for this year, creating a `datetime.date` object with content like this: "2013-01-01". I then converted this to a string:

```
this_year = (datetime.date(datetime.date.today().isocalendar()[0], 1, 1))
test2 = ("'"+str(this_year)+"'")
```

Then I queried the SQLite DB:

```
cursr = con.cursor()
con.text_factory = str
cursr.execute("""select ID from TEST_TABLE where WEEK_IN = 13 and DATE_IN > ? """,[test2])

result = cursr.fetchall()
print result

[('1',), ('2',)]
```

This returns the IDs 1 and 2, but this is no good, because ID 1 has '2012' as the year.

The strange thing is, if I don't use datetime for the string, but create the var manually, IT WORKS CORRECTLY.

```
test2 = ('2013-01-01')

cursr.execute("""select ID from TEST_TABLE where WEEK_IN = 13 and DATE_IN > ? """,[test2])
result = cursr.fetchall()
print result
[('2',)]
```

So why won't the query work correctly when I create the string via datetime?
A string is a string, right? So what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of converting `this_year` into a string, just leave it as a `datetime.date` object:

```
this_year = DT.date(DT.date.today().year,1,1)
```

---

```
import sqlite3
import datetime as DT

this_year = (DT.date(DT.date.today().isocalendar()[0], 1, 1))
# this_year = ("'"+str(this_year)+"'")
# this_year = DT.date(DT.date.today().year,1,1)
with sqlite3.connect(':memory:') as conn:
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    sql = '''CREATE TABLE TEST_TABLE
        ("ID" TEXT,
        "DATE_IN" DATE,
        "WEEK_IN" number)
    '''
    cursor.execute(sql)
    sql = 'INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE(ID, DATE_IN, WEEK_IN) VALUES (?,?,?)'
    cursor.executemany(sql, [[1,'2012-03-25',13],[2,'2013-03-25',13],])
    sql = 'SELECT ID FROM TEST_TABLE where WEEK_IN = 13 and DATE_IN > ?'
    cursor.execute(sql, [this_year])
    for row in cursor:
        print(row)
```

yields

```
(u'2',)
```

---

The sqlite3 database adapter will quote arguments for you when you write parametrized SQL and use the 2-argument form of `cursor.execute`. So you do not need (or want) to quote arguments manually yourself.

So

```
this_year = str(this_year)
```

instead of

```
this_year = ("'"+str(this_year)+"'")
```

also works, but as shown above, both lines are unnecessary, since `sqlite3` will accept `datetime` objects as arguments as well.

also works.

Since sqlite3 automatically quotes arguments, when you manually add quotes, the final argument gets two sets of quotes. The SQL ends up comparing

```
In [59]: '2012-03-25' > "'2013-01-01'"
Out[59]: True
```

which is why both rows were (erroneously) returned.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because of how you're creating your date in the `test2` variable.

In the first example, when you use the `datetime module`, you accidentally introduce extra quotation marks:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> this_year = datetime.date(datetime.date.today().isocalendar()[0], 1, 1)
>>> test2 = "'" + str(this_year) + "'"
>>> print test2
"'2013-01-01'"
```

However, in your second example, you only set `test2` to equal the date, which worked.

```
>>> test2 = '2013-01-01'
'2013-01-01'
```

To fix it, just modify your first example to look like this:

```
this_year = datetime.date(datetime.date.today().isocalendar()[0], 1, 1)
test2 = str(this_year)
```

As a side note, note that I've removed the parenthesis around your variables, since they were redundant.

Comment: thanks for the info ... it was indeed the conversion to str that messed things up.

Comment: @ the risk of sounding cheezy ... tks to everybody for responding 
so quickly .. this was my first post @ stackoverflow ... speed and accuracy of yr responses blew me away. Waw !

Comment: @user2071786: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please accept Michael0x2a's answer if you found it helpful.